# IF Statement Doesn't Separate Empty or Isset

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, isset

I've created a membership where people can make a profile. What I'd like to do is show "Create a Profile" if one hasn't been created yet and "Edit Profile" and "View Profile" if it hasn't. I've tried using an if empty and if isset code setup, however neither works in differentiating who has a profile and who doesn't.

Here's the relevant code:

```
    $colname_rs_Members_tbl = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
  $colname_rs_Members_tbl = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_members_db_conn, $members_db_conn);
$query_rs_Members_tbl = sprintf("SELECT * FROM members_tbl WHERE username = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_rs_Members_tbl, "text"));
$rs_Members_tbl = mysql_query($query_rs_Members_tbl, $members_db_conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_Members_tbl = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_Members_tbl);
$totalRows_rs_Members_tbl = mysql_num_rows($rs_Members_tbl);

$first = $row_rs_Members_tbl['first_name'];
$last = $row_rs_Members_tbl['last_name'];
$profile_url_name = strtolower($first . $last);

$colname_rs_Actors_tbl = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['$profile_url_name'])) {
  $colname_rs_Actors_tbl = $_SESSION['$profile_url_name'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_profiles_db_conn, $profiles_db_conn);
$query_rs_Actors_tbl = sprintf("SELECT profile_url_name FROM actors_tbl WHERE profile_url_name = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_rs_Actors_tbl, "text"));
$rs_Actors_tbl = mysql_query($query_rs_Actors_tbl, $profiles_db_conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_Actors_tbl = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_Actors_tbl);
$totalRows_rs_Actors_tbl = mysql_num_rows($rs_Actors_tbl);

<p align="center"><?php if (isset($row_rs_Actors_tbl['profile_url_name'])) {echo '<a href="http://profiles.oneforestfilms.com/actors/add_profile.php">Create Actor Profile</a><br />';} else {echo '<a href="http://profiles.oneforestfilms.com/actors/edit_profile.php?profile_url_name=<?php echo $profile_url_name; ?>">Edit Actor Profile</a><br />
    <a href="http://profiles.oneforestfilms.com/actors/actor.php?profile_url_name=<?php echo $profile_url_name; ?>">View Actor Profile</a>';} ?></p>
```

Now I've tried this also:

```
<?php $profile = $row_rs_Actors_tbl['profile_url_name']; if (empty($profile)) {echo...
```

And I also tried that with isset. The problem is that the same thing is displaying for someone with a profile as it is for someone without one. Does anyone have an answer to this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You really need some separation of concerns, here. Mixing SQL with HTML is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to care, but not enough, about validating if the user has a profile or not as you constantly check if the `$_SESSION` variables are set, but you then execute the MySQL statements regardless.

Also, the line `if (isset($_SESSION['$profile_url_name'])) {` has `$profile_url_name` in single quotes - which means it's value won't be used; instead it will literaly by used as "$profile_url_name". This may be fine if you actually named your `$_SESSION` index such as `$_SESSION['$profile_url_name']`, but it just looks odd considering you actually have a variable named `$profile_url_name`. I'm thinking it's supposed to be something like `$_SESSION['first_name last_name']`?

As a start to fix the issue, it may be better to clean up the exist code and separate things a little more clearly. Try something like this:

```
<?php
$valid_user = false;
$row_rs_Members_tbl = '';
$row_rs_Actors_tbl = '';
$profile_url_name = '';
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
    // first-check, success; we have a set username
    mysql_select_db($database_members_db_conn, $members_db_conn);
    $query_rs_Members_tbl = sprintf("SELECT * FROM members_tbl WHERE username = %s", GetSQLValueString($_SESSION['MM_Username'], "text"));
    $rs_Members_tbl = mysql_query($query_rs_Members_tbl, $members_db_conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rs_Members_tbl = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_Members_tbl);

    $profile_url_name = strtolower($row_rs_Members_tbl['first_name'] . $row_rs_Members_tbl['last_name']);
    if (isset($_SESSION[$profile_url_name])) {
        // there is a session-value set for this name; good chance we have a profile!
        mysql_select_db($database_profiles_db_conn, $profiles_db_conn);
        $query_rs_Actors_tbl = sprintf("SELECT profile_url_name FROM actors_tbl WHERE profile_url_name = %s", GetSQLValueString($_SESSION[$profile_url_name], "text"));
        $rs_Actors_tbl = mysql_query($query_rs_Actors_tbl, $profiles_db_conn) or die(mysql_error());

        if (mysql_num_rows($rs_Actors_tvl) > 0) {
            // w00t, we found a profile =]
            $row_rs_Actors_tbl = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_Actors_tbl);
            $valid_user = true;
        }
    }
}
?>
<p align="center">
    <?php if ($valid_user === true) { ?>
        <a href="http://profiles.oneforestfilms.com/actors/add_profile.php">Create Actor Profile</a>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="http://profiles.oneforestfilms.com/actors/edit_profile.php?profile_url_name=<?=urlencode($profile_url_name);?>">Edit Actor Profile</a>
        <br />
        <a href="http://profiles.oneforestfilms.com/actors/actor.php?profile_url_name=<?=urlencode($profile_url_name);?>">View Actor Profile</a>
    <?php } ?>
</p>
```

In the above example, I've removed references to your `$totalRows_*` variables as they weren't used. Also, I replaced `$_SESSION['$profile_url_name']` with `$_SESSION[$profile_url_name]`, just in case.